# GAE - !MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Deploying..."

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I tried to deploy my test GWT app with Eclipse Indigo 3.7 but I get this error thrown. Here logs report...

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2012-01-07 05:48:42.359 !MESSAGE An
>   internal error occurred during: "Deploying TestApp01 to Google".
>   !STACK 0 java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:132)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

What can it be? Where to start looking the error comes from? How to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Occasionally deployments fail for network reasons or server errors.  Have you tried again?  You may need to "rollback" your deployment - if so, you'll get a more specific error message.

Comment: Emm... How to rollback? No deployment was successful yet :( How to get a more specific error message then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem as follows...

So I had to dig deeper... 
*the problem was definitely not in GWT project or IDE or SDK etc but in my OS time settings and, as I can get it, the google server time settings for my time zone :S*
For some reason my PC time is not the same as the google server's one is expecting my computer to have... So I had to set **-1 HOUR** on my PC to equal the server and client machines' times :|

Only then I could sign in google account with eclipse google gwt sdk plugin; I am not pretty sure is it a common case for this kind of error but in my case that was helpful :)

Hope that saves one's day

Answer (score 0):

I tried eclipse and then also tried the command line deploy described here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading

In the end it was Kaspersky Virus scanner on my system. I had to disable it because its firewall & web protection was blocking something. Once i did that, everything (eclipse and command line) started working. I hope it will help some.